# How does the option type work in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#

So I've been reading the Expert F# book by Apress, mostly using it as a reference when building a toy-ish F# library, but there's one thing I've failed to grasp and that's the "Option" type.

How does it work and what is it's real world usage?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The option type is at least *similar* to `Nullable<T>` and reference types in C#. A value of type `Option<T>` is either `None` which means there's no encapsuated value, or `Some` with a particular value of `T`. This is just like the way a `Nullable<int>` in C# is *either* the null value, *or* has an associated `int` - and the way a `String` value in C# is *either* a null reference, *or* refers to a String object.

When you use an option value, you generally specify two paths - one for the case where there *is* an associated value, and one where there *isn't*. In other words, this code:

```
let stringLength (str:Option<string>) =
  match str with
  | Some(v) -> v.Length
  | None -> -1
```

is similar to:

```
int StringLength(string str)
{
    if (str != null)
    {
        return str.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I believe the general idea is that *forcing* you (well, nearly) to handle the "no associated value/object" case makes your code more robust.

Comment: The string-length example is typically how it's _not_ done in FP ;). This way you force unsafe business logic down the line (checking for -1, and remembering that). More idiomatic would be to inform the consumer that there was no string (null or `None`), and return `Some length` or `None`. This'll keep your coding secure, NRE-free and, hopefully less buggy. To help with this, so that you don't have to repeat the matching all the time, FP defines `Option.map/bind` functions. Your last statement is very true though :)

Comment: (as an aside, strings in F# are mostly safe, unless consumed from an untrusted source, which further alleviates the need for null checking)

Answer (score 6):

One of the best examples of real-world usage is for the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) pattern in .Net.  See the first half of

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!181.entry

for a discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It's used when a function or method should "maybe" or "optionally" return a value. In C# you'd probably return null, or return a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) or possibly a Nullable for value types.

The downside of returning null (the most common case) is that it's not type safe: null is an instance of all types, so you get into all kinds of hairy null reference situations later on.

The Option type is a so called disciminated union type with two constructors: None and Some a. None explicitly indicates that you don't have a value. Basically it's the Null Object pattern generalized.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, the Option type is nothing special -- it's just another discriminated union. You could define it yourself in one line:

```
type 'a Option = None | Some of 'a
```

The utility, as others have pointed out, is that pattern matching will let you safely deconstruct this, instead of checking for null or using some hack-workaround to indicate if a value isn't really a value.

Answer (score 2):

You use it when a value is optional. One use is to have a kind of 'null reference', e.g.

```
 val x : int option ref = None
```

Then you can later update x to Some v. You use it with the match statement, e.g.

```
 match !x with (* dereference x *)
    None -> (* No value, do something *)
 |  Some v -> (* Value v, do something else *)
```

Comment: I know this was answered a long time ago, but generally speaking, references are discouraged in F#. It's possible, of course, but often a sign if code smell. It is better to just use options, you get type safe guard against 'no value' and NRE's for free.

Answer (score 1):

A functional pattern using the option type:

When you need to change parts of a recursive data structure, such as a tree or a list,
you will want to reuse as much of the existing data structure as possible. The option type
can help you with this.
These two functions both replaces all occurrences of the number 5 with 7,
but the first one copies the entire tree. The second one does not.

```
type Tree = Leaf of int
      | Node of Tree * Tree

let rec replace_no_sharing tree =
    match tree with
    | Leaf 5      -> Leaf 7
    | Leaf x      -> Leaf x
    | Node (a, b) -> Node (replace_no_sharing a, replace_no_sharing b)

let replace_with_sharing tree =
    let rec replace_option tree =
        match tree with
        | Leaf 5      -> Leaf 7 |> Some
        | Leaf x      -> None
        | Node (a, b) -> match replace_option a, replace_option b with
                         | None, None     -> None
                         | Some a, Some b -> Node (a, b) |> Some
                         | Some a, None   -> Node (a, b) |> Some
                         | None, Some b   -> Node (a, b) |> Some
    match replace_option tree with
    | None      -> tree
    | Some tree -> tree
```

It might not be necessary in all cases, but it's a nice technique to know.