# Why can't certain Silverlight objects be Nullable<> types?

Tags: c#, nullable

**Apparently you can't have a *Nullable<Rectangle>* in Silverlight. I'd like to know the technical reasons why not and how many objects this may apply to?**

Today I accidentally started a small [comment flamewar](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=309) after stating that the "Rectangle" type was not a Nullable type. That is you can't have a "*Nullable<Rectangle>*" or a "*Rectangle?*"

My mistake was in testing it in Silverlight only and assuming that the behaviour of a Silverlight System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle carried over to the System.Drawing.Rectangle type in .Net. Shame on me. I have since deleted my comments as they added no value to Stack Overflow.

If anyone can answer this question fully it would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a matter of terminology, `Rectangle?` or `Nullable<Rectangle>` is called a *nullable type*. `Rectangle` itself isn’t. It is either a *value type* (in the case of System.Drawing.Rectangle) or a *reference type* (in the case of the Silverlight one).

Comment: Please note that System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle is in .NET, the full framework. It's part of WPF. Silverlight is a subset of WPF. System.Drawing.Rectangle is something completely different, it's not a WPF/Silverlight API, but is meant for use with GDI and Windows Forms, which has a different layout and coordinate system entirely, and thus cannot use the old System.Drawing.Rectangle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` can only be used with value types, or structs, and System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle is a reference type, or class.  You don't need to use `Nullable<T>`, since you can already assign a null reference to a variable of type System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect = null;
```

By contrast, System.Drawing.Rectangle is a value type, so it cannot have a value of null.  The default value is a rectangle of all zeros.

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = null; // Does not compile
System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = 
    default(System.Drawing.Rectangle); // All fields are zero
```

Comment: So the .Net Rectangle is a simple struct, whereas the Silverlight version requires all the extra UIElement plumbing (which is of course requires it to be an object). Cool. Thanks for that.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: Perhaps you're looking for System.Windows.Rect?

Comment: Additionally to this answer, you can place your cursor on the word “Rectangle” (or any other type) and press F12 to find out whether it is a struct or a class. Even better, you can set Visual Studio to colour them differently, which is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer would be to consider the differences between Option types and Nullable types, which is incidentally covered in the ECMA Standard for Common Language Infrastructure for Generics.

A [great explanation of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947003/f-why-arent-option-types-compatible-with-nullable-types) has already been given for F# on StackOverflow.

So you don't want a Nullable<Rectangle>.  You want an Option<Rectangle>.

See MSDN Documentation: [Core.Option Module (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx)