# Can a record have a nullable field?

Tags: f#

Is it legal for a record to have a nullable field such as:

```
type MyRec = { startDate : System.Nullable<DateTime>; }
```

This example does build in my project, but is this good practice if it is legal, and what problems if any does this introduce?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is legal, but F# encourage using option types instead:

```
type MyRec = { startDate : option<DateTime>; }
```

By using option you can easily pattern match against options and other operations to transform option values as for example map values (by using `Option.map`), and abstractions such as the Maybe monad (by using `Option.bind`), whereas with nullable you can't since only value types can be made nullables.

You will notice most F# functions (such as `List.choose`) work with options instead of nullables. Some language features like [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) are interpreted as the F# option type.

However in some cases, when you need to interact with C# you may want to use Nullable.

When usign Linq to query a DB you may consider using the [Linq.Nullable Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324123.aspx) and the [Nullable operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370984.aspx)

Comment: Yes, interacting with C# was the exact reason why I was asking. I am querying sql server and transferring the data into records for use in C#.

Answer (score 5):

F# does not allow types that are declared in F# to be null. However, if you're using types that are not defined in F#, you are still allowed to use null. This is why your code is still legal. This is needed for inter-operability, because you may need to pass null to a .NET library or accept it as a result.

But I would say it is not a good practice unless your need is specifically of inter-operability. As others pointed out, you can use the option feature. However, this doesn't create an optional record field whose value you don't need to specify when creating it. To create a value of the record type, you still need to provide the value of the optional field.

Also, you can mark a type with the AllowNullLiteral attribute, and F# compiler would allow null as a value for that specific type, even if it is a type declared in F#. But AllowNullLiteral can't be applied to record types.

Oh and I almost forgot to mention: option types are NOT compatible with nullable types. Something that I kind of naively expected to just work (stupid me!). See [this nice SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/947003/2671089) for details.